# disable WIN32API focused control highlighting

Tags: winapi

how can I remove the outline that is drawn when a control such as a button or checkbox is selected?

```
HWND chk=CreateWindow("button",s,
  BS_FLAT|BS_AUTOCHECKBOX|BS_LEFTTEXT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
  x,y,w,h,p,id,hInst,NULL);
```

http://www.thevbzone.com/L3_3.gif

Comment: By "selected", you are talking about focus, not being checked?

Comment: yes the control that has focus gets these ugly dashed outlines i want them gone : p

Comment: Owner draw is the only way. But it's bad UI design to not indicate the item with focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The focus rectangles, like underlines for mnemonics, are shown depending on the UI state.  By default, these things are hidden, *unless* the user initiated the dialog or menu via the keyboard.  The idea being that if they're using the keyboard, these visual cues are useful, but if they're using the mouse (or touch), they're just clutter.

The UI state is accessible through [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) using the `SPI_GET`/`SETKEYBOARDCUES`, but I don't recommend changing that as it affects the user's experience with all applications, not just yours.

Regular UI controls decide how to draw themselves based on their state and the current UI state.  If you want to change the appearance for your application, you'd have to use whatever feature the controls offer for "owner drawing," which can be quite a bit of work, and not all control types offer the appropriate overrides.  I don't know of any per-control bit that can suppress the focus rectangles.

If you're using a modern application, the focus indicators are often much cleaner looking than the dashed rectangles you get on the old style buttons.  Make sure you've [enabled visual styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx) if you just want the modern look and don't really want to make it harder for your keyboard users to use your application.

Comment: how would I go about enabling visual styles with the gcc compiler?

Comment: Owner drawing shouldn't be that bad, since [`DrawFrameControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`DrawThemePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implement the default drawing logic and lets you control the state to draw, so for example the "hot" state can be masked out.

Comment: does gcc support application manifests and7or is C++ a requirement? I'd rather use C

Comment: To enable visual styles with the gcc toolchain, I assume you have to create a manifest explicitly.  The manifest is just a blob of XML stored in UTF-16le in as a special resource (like your string resources and dialog templates).  So however you embed files into your resources should solve the problem.  It might make a good SO question on its own.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. After creating the button:

```
    if (hWndButton[i] != NULL)
    {
        SendMessage(hWndButton[i], WM_CHANGEUISTATE, (WPARAM)(0x10001),(LPARAM)(0));
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the actual name instead of 0x10001?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the WM_SETFOCUS msg of the button class. I've already written all the code. This is called subclassing in win32.

```
#include <windows.h>

// window callback
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// redefining button class
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
WNDPROC oldButtonProc;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, char* cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    const char WNDClsName[] = "no-name";


    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = WNDClsName;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(
        WNDClsName,
        "Caption",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, // parent
        NULL, // menu
        hInstance, // instance handle
        NULL);  // additional application data

    HWND button1 = CreateWindow(
        "button", // class
        "", // text
        WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, // style
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, // x,y
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, // w,h
        hwnd, // parent
        (HMENU) 101,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    oldButtonProc = (WNDPROC) SetClassLong(button1, GCL_WNDPROC, (LONG)ButtonProc);
    DestroyWindow(button1);

    button1 = CreateWindow(
        "button", // class
        "Doit!", // text
        WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, // style
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, // x,y
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, // w,h
        hwnd, // parent
        (HMENU) 101,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, cmdShow);

    // run the message loop

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    SetWindowLong(button1, GCL_WNDPROC, (LONG)oldButtonProc);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            short width = LOWORD(lParam);
            short height = HIWORD(lParam);

            MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 101), width/2-40, height/2-10, 80, 20, 0);
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, 0);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_SETFOCUS)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return CallWindowProc(oldButtonProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```